# uniMRCP and pocketsphinx testing on windows 7

Tags: cmusphinx, unimrcp

I've successfully built uniMRCP with sphinxbase and pocketsphinx on visual studio 2010. **The problem that I have right now is I have no idea on how to test pocketsphinx in uniMRCP**. By the way, I'm already familiar in using pocketsphinx alone.

Regarding uniMRCP, All I know right now is how to execute unimrcpserver.exe and unimrcpclient.exe then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Integration is covered here:

https://code.google.com/p/unimrcp/wiki/PocketSphinxPlugin

Basically you need to edit XML files to use the right engine for speech recognition and then just run unimrcp server. Also edit pocketsphinx configuration file to point to the data files.

Then you can play with the client or configure dialplan on Asterisk to connect to the server.